# XDebug: IDE Key settings cannot be changed

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

I was following the instruction on xdebug site, I want to use PhpStorm as the IDE. So I follow the steps and set the following in `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` :

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.4-5.6-vc11.dll
DBGP_IDEKEY=PHPSTORM
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

I also set `DBGP_IDEKEY=PHPSTORM` in environment variables. At Chrome side, I set IDE key to `PHPSTORM`as well.

But no matter how hard I try, each time when I restart XAMPP Apache, in `phpinfo()` it always shows the IDE Key is `XDEBUG_ECLIPSE`. I don't know where is it set and why doesn't it get overwritten.

Comment: PhpStorm does not care about IDE key -- it will work with ANY.

Comment: As to "why it changes" -- check `phpinfo()` output -- topmost table -- it shows all config files PHP has loaded. Maybe it does not load that .ini file? Because, AFAIK, it should not be doing "key is set to another one" after web server restart. By default xdebug uses no key at all ... so it must be coming from somewhere else...